# Hibernate/MySQL: Hangs after SQL exception

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

Everytime I run hibernate and I purposely throw a duplicate key exception, it will hang when I try to access the table that threw the duplicate key exception.

Here is the log from the first run with the exception.

```
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:52 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateDB]
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:53 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:54 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate
INFO: HHH000229: Running schema validator
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:54 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator validate
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:54 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: hibernateDB.DOCTOR_INFO
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:54 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [id, name, appointment_id, specialty_id]
Hibernate: insert into DOCTOR_INFO (appointment_id, name, specialty_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
Feb 25, 2014 12:18:54 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Duplicate entry 'Bill Russel' for key 'UK_mg4wu6e2eumcqcrcod6hy8lmk'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3556)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at edu.cs157b.hibernate.PresentationLayer.main(PresentationLayer.java:16)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'Bill Russel' for key 'UK_mg4wu6e2eumcqcrcod6hy8lmk'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1041)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2825)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2441)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
    ... 22 more
```

Here is the log from a second run:

```
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateDB]
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:07 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:08 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Feb 24, 2014 11:56:08 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table if exists DOCTOR_INFO
```

Here is where I run the code:

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class PresentationLayer {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Doctor doctor = new Doctor();
        doctor.setName("Bill Russell");
        session.save(doctor);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    Session session1 = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session1.beginTransaction();
    Doctor doctor1 = new Doctor();
    doctor.setName("Bill Russell");
    session1.save(doctor);
    session1.getTransaction().commit();
    session1.close();

        sessionFactory.close();

    }

}
```

Here is my `Doctor` class

```
package edu.cs157b.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="DOCTOR_INFO")
public class Doctor {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int specialty_id;
    private String appointment_id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(unique=true)
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSpecialty_id() {
        return specialty_id;
    }

    public void setSpecialty_id(int specialty_id) {
        this.specialty_id = specialty_id;
    }

    public String getAppointment_id() {
        return appointment_id;
    }

    public void setAppointment_id(String appointment_id) {
        this.appointment_id = appointment_id;
    }
}
```

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateDB</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">***</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->

        <mapping class="edu.cs157b.hibernate.Student"/>
        <mapping class="edu.cs157b.hibernate.Doctor"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: check the locks on the table in question

Comment: What happens when you disable the schema creation? Works ok?

Comment: nope it doesn't work but I updated the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use validate for

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

*validate- existing schema
*update- only update your schema once created
*create- create schema every time

Comment: do you know why this only happens when I use the `Doctor` class & not the `Student` class. This is very weird to me

Comment: It mean when you commit values to Student it will not drop and re create?? Anyway try having validate instead create. It should work

Comment: nope it doesn't work. but i seem to have an idea of whats causing the issue. Let me update the question

Answer (score 0):

Apply the best pratice `begin/commit/rollback` pattern for transaction:

```
try
{
  begin tx;
  do operations;
  commit tx;
}
catch(exception)
{
  rollback tx; 
}
```

You don't close session after first execution due to uncaunght exception and - with a connection pool of 1 - the next execution hangs!